# how to send data to parent component in angular2

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing

I have app described below:

**components:** 
   1. Parent
   2. child1
   3. child2
   3. child13

so child1 and child2 comes under parent, and child13 comes under child1.

I am using RouterConfig to navigation. so templates are describle below.

**parent.html**

```
this is parent click on childs
  <a [routerLink]="['Child1']">Child1</a>
<a [routerLink]="['Child1']">Child2</a>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**Child1.html**

```
this is child1 please click on grand-child 
<a [routerLink]="['Child13']">grand-child</a>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**Question:** I want to execute function in parent component from child1 and child13.

**how to send or execute parent function?**

I have used event emitter but it requires child component html tag in parent.html file to define mapping but 
here I can't because these component using router to navigation.

Comment: If you want communication between mentioned two components, you can use service as they are sibling components.

Comment: thanks for your reply, 
Currently I am using service but it is like extra implementation of things.... 
I wanted to use direct child to parent communication?